# Disable ADFS Authentication for Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs, adfs2.0, adfs2.1

We have an MVC application which uses ADFS as its authentication method. All is working as should.
We are now beginning to add in 'areas' into the application to separate certain parts out.
One of these areas needs to allow complete anonymous access.
Is there a way to disable ADFS for a particular area within an MVC application?

We have tried overriding the webconfig within the area, however, no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [AllowAnonymous] attribute on controller methods in that area?